# How to change origin in a SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I need to change origin for existing git repository. I am using SourceTree. I search a lot but has not fined the answer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using `Source Tree` we can change the origin of our repository from the `Settings` option:

[image]

Edit the origin and save it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. First you have to add a new remote through 'Repository' -> 'Repository Settings...' -> 'Add' [(Changing remote repository)](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/changing-remote-repository-path-on-sourcetree-using-git-or-mercurial-785616227.html)
2. Stay in the 'Repository Settings' menu and edit the current origin.
   Uncheck the 'Default remote' checkbox and rename the remote (e.g. old_origin).
3. Now edit the new remote that was added in step 1 and check the 'Default remote' checkbox, the remote will be automatically named to origin.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a new origin or remote you can either. Click setting (on the top right of SourceTree) and go to the remote tab and add a new origin. Alternatively you could do this via the inbuilt terminal by running something like

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have two "remotes" (for example "origin" and "alternate") and you want to make "alternate" your default remote:

In the Settings (top right corner)

- First select "origin" and press the "Edit" button

  - Rename "origin" to something else
  - Remove the checkmark "Default remote"
  - Press "OK" to store these changes
- Then select that "alternate" and press "Edit"

  - Check the "Default remote" checkbox
  - This automatically renames "alternate" to "origin" (that is why you had to rename your original "origin" first)
  - Press "OK" to store these changes
- And press "OK" again to exit the Settings screen